# Scraping em Python. Montar um insert

Tags: html, python, scraping

Gostaria de extrair essa tabela utilizando talvez Scraping em Python:

https://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/pagamentos-e-parcelamentos/codigos-de-receita/codigos-de-receita-de-contribuicao-previdenciaria

Gostaria de saber se é possível extrair essa tabela de modo que seja montado o sql de insert como abaixo:

```
INSERT INTO TABELA
(CAMPO1, CAMPO2)
VALUES
(1007, 'Contribuinte Individual - Recolhimento Mensal - NIT/PIS/PASEP')
```

só tenho o python instalado. não tenho nada feito.

Comment: Sim é, fez algum código? Ta usando alguma lib?

Comment: Sabes fazer o insert/conecção com a db? Ou queres que a resposta cubra essa parte também? Devias colocar o que já tens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Começando do começo  - em geral usariamos os módulos requests e beautifulsoup para ler o conteúdo de uma página web - mas também é possível fazer sim.
Temos um outro problema que essas páginas da receita usam uma autoridade certificadora para SSL que não está configurada nem nos navegadores, nem em instalaões do Python. COm Python puro, [precisamos criar um contexto de SSL e desligar explicitamente a verificação do certificado](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600583/python-3-urllib-ignore-ssl-certificate-verification) - fica:

```
import urllib.request
import ssl
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
url = "https://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/pagamentos-e-parcelamentos/codigos-de-receita/codigos-de-receita-de-contribuicao-previdenciaria"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read().decode("utf-8")
```

Com a biblioteca requests instalada, fica apenas:

```
import requests
url = "https://idg.receita.fazenda.gov.br/orientacao/tributaria/pagamentos-e-parcelamentos/codigos-de-receita/codigos-de-receita-de-contribuicao-previdenciaria"
data = requests.get(url, verify=False).text
```

O próximo passo é espiar o código HTML da página - é fácil verificar que é um HTML que, apesar de verboso, tem uma única tabela na página (elemento "table"), que está bem estruturado com tags `<tr>`e `<td>` todas fechadas de forma bem formada. 
Sem nenhuma biblioteca auxiliar, o Python tem a classe `html.parser.HTMLParser` que pode nos ajudar. É uma das poucas APIs na biblitoeca padrão que requer que seja feita uma sub-classe de uma classe já existente para seu uso. Felizmente, só precisamos de 3 métodos: um que é chamado quando o parser encontra uma nova tag (qualquer que seja), um que é chamado quando fecha uma tag, e outro que é chamado quando o parser encontra conteúdo de texto dentro das tags. [Confira a documentação do HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html).

Ou seja - basta colocarmos alguns atributos de estado, atributos para guardar os dados recuperados, e alguns "if"'s nos métodos que verificam o início e fim de tag - e, assim, quando estivermos no método que é chamado com o conteúdo de texto das tags, um único "if" verifica se estamos dentro de uma célula de tabela, e se sim, guarda os dados. Isso de quebra ignora todos os tags malucos que tem nessa página - "strong", "p", "span" dentro dos próprios "td"s:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

class TableParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.table_data = []
        self.inside_table = False
        self.inside_tr = False
        self.inside_td = False
        self.tmp_row_data = []
        self.tmp_cell_data = []

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        if tag == "table":
            self.inside_table = True
        elif tag == "tr":
            self.inside_tr = True
        elif tag == "td":
            self.inside_td = True

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag == "table":
            self.inside_table = False
        elif tag == "tr":
            self.inside_tr = False
            self.table_data.append(self.tmp_row_data)
            self.tmp_row_data = []
        elif tag == "td":
            self.inside_td = False
            self.tmp_row_data.append(" ".join(self.tmp_cell_data).strip())
            self.tmp_cell_data = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if self.inside_td:
            self.tmp_cell_data.append(data)
```

E come essa classe no lugar, podemos ter uma lista contendo listas com cada linha da tabela da página:

```
parser = TableParser()
parser.feed(data)
lines = parser.table_data[1:]
```

E agora, para "montar os inserts", é só usa um "for" om a db api do Python - e fazer as chamadas ao banco. Isso muda um pouco de banco para banco. Para só montar os "inserts", como você disse, podemos gravar uma equência de inserts nos arquivo texto:

```
with open("codigo_receita.sql", "wt") as file_:
    for item, codigo, especificacao in lines:
          especificao = especificacao.replace("'", "''")
          file_.write(f"""INSERT INTO TABELA (CAMPO1, CAMPO2) VALUES ({codigo}, '{especificacao}');\n""")
```